# Which headers and functions can I use in loadable kernel modules (except external libraries)?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Section 2 of the Linux man pages contains `system calls`.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/

After finding this link, I say "OK! I use this reference for developing every modules, It is complete".

But it seems I can not use some functions of this section (like `bind(2)`). After including required headers (like `<sys/socket.h>`) the module compilation failed.

Some functions/macros like `printk` does not listed in the section 2. Many people used Linux Apis that I could not find any official reference for it (just like `printk`). I don't know how they found these functions? (May be by reading whole source code of kernel instead of reading any reference)

Some functions like `memset` describes in section 3 (user space libraries) but kernel module developer can use it without any error!

Where I can found a **COMPLETE** reference of available **headers** and **functions**  when developing a loadable kernel modules? (Something like MSDN and WINDDK references)

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

/* A complete list of availabe headers and functions is missing! */

static int my_init(void)
{
    return  0;
}

static void my_exit(void)
{
    return;
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

Comment: It's easy, just look inside the _include_ directory under the root of your Kernel source tree ;)

Comment: Linux doesn't have a complete reference of all the available headers and functions. Your function reference is pretty much reading the headers in the kernel include directory. Even if a reference existed, it would just get out of date so quickly since the Linux kernel doesn't care about backwards compatibility (in kernel interfaces).

Answer (score 4):

As you know, the Kernel is quite a big, big and independent beast. This means that you cannot include anything which is not found under your kernel source tree.

When you're implementing your module, that means the only things you can link to is what you got in :

- The kernel source tree itself
- Another module you've made (I would recommend to avoid this scenario though whenever possible ... )

*Note that you will be able to use the functions only if they are exported. You can check this using the `nm` utility on the compiled `.ko` file of a module. If you want to export some symbols of your module, you have to use the [macro `EXPORT_SYMBOL`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/export.h#L48).*

Be careful not to confuse user-space includes, usually found under /usr/include with the kernel module headers (which you are likely wanting to link against).

In the example you gave, the *sys/socket.h* is the location of the header after a `make headers_install`. At this location, it is meant to be used by userspace applications. This is *NOT* what you want when you are programming a module.

I think you have to look deeper in the use of sockets in the kernel. By googling up a little, I found  [-> this <-](http://lwn.net/Articles/187453/)  on LWN and checked the *include/linux/net.h* header of my 3.8 kernel source tree. The patch described in the link is integrated in the kernel and is likely to be what you are looking for.

The **memset** example is also an illustration of what I explained this far : if you want to use it in a common application, you'll have to include the *string.h* header, which is simply located at */usr/include/string.h*. Its kernel equivalent is found under ...

> /your-kernel-source-tree-dir/include/linux/string.h

*Et voila !* You can use **memset** and friends inside any piece of kernel code, as long as you include the right header !

Thus, when you feel some frustration, thinking *Man, I was able to use this by simply including this header in my apps ...* Take a deep look at the kernel source tree (or have `grep` do it for you ;) ). You are very likely to find what you are looking for !

Comment: This is incomplete.
For a loadable module, he can't just any function he finds in the headers of the kernel tree he's using.
The function/data has to be ExPORTED via the EXPORT_SYMBOL macro.

Comment: @AdelQodmani Which is the case for any header you will find under the `include` directory of the kernel source tree

Comment: Not necessarily, one example is the system calls, you can find them in /src/include/linux/syscalls.h but none of them is exported.

Comment: @AdelQodmani Anyway, I edited my answer to include extra information about the symbol exporting :)

Comment: Now that looks more accurate :) -1 removed

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge there is no such complete reference for kernel module programming. I suggest you study the LDD3 basic sections  and http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN978 for a beginner.